# MySQL InnoDB Update-Select?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am using Gearman workers to accept jobs from a MySQL database. The procedure for these workers getting a job is something like:

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM jobs WHERE job_id = 'foobarbaz' AND status = 'WAITING';
```

Now, if that query returns one row, then the worker knows its been given a valid job and proceeds to work on it. But of course the risk is while working on it another worker might take up the job, too.

To prevent this I'm thinking how can I atomically SELECT the data needed to proceed with the job as well as update the status of it if it was valid? I thought perhaps of doing the UPDATE on the row status with the job ID and then testing affected rows, but wasn't sure if there was a more sensible way to go about it.

Thanks.

Comment: if you want similar and easy solution, you should use two queries
`update status = 'IN_PROCESS' where job_id = 'foobarbaz' and statu='VACANT'`
then
`SELECT foo, bar FROM jobs WHERE job_id = 'foobarbaz' AND status = 'IN_PROCESS';`

Comment: value of status should be set to 'VACANT' at time of insertion or as default. So it will be selectable until status='IN_PROCESS' which you will set only when it is selected to be proceeded

Comment: That is my proposed solution, but I suspected there was a better one, perhaps using transactions or something?

Comment: Besides, what about the case when two threads think they are updating the status to IN_PROCESS?

Comment: Locks 'READ LOCK' are used professionally but they are put at table level and they would not allow concurrency in reading. iF you want to have look http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Transaction is not solution in your case, Hope you know the concept of transaction

Comment: Yes `if (select (update jobs set status = 'IN_PROCESS' where job_id = 'foobarbaz' and statu='VACANT'))=1 then --(do select that job)-- ` Now it ensures that if one thread has changed the status, Other will find the result of update as `0` otherwise `1`

Comment: I think I may have found what I'm looking for: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html